# Is it possible to have the keyboard be visible without the address bar being visible on Chrome android?

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome

It's a very useful feature that the address bar disappears when scrolling on Chrome android, saving valuable screen space.  But as soon as you click on an text `<input>` and the keyboard pops up the address bar reappears.

I assume it's not a bug and google have done it for a reason.  I'd be interested if anyone has an idea to the rationale behind it.

Regardless of that, the question is, is it possible to change this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input could be used to ask for your password or other personal data. Showing the address bar allows you to make sure that you're on the right site and not on a fake clone. I'll admit I have not verified this information, but that would be my guess.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, and probably uncircumventable in that case.